# Simple problem formulation for EM algorithm

Tags: classification, mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

I understand the EM algorithm, I understand for example how we get $Q(\theta, \theta^t)$, but I have trouble translating a real-world problem into the EM framework.

For example, I'm given this problem where each document $x$ is classified into a class $y$, where there are $M$ documents and $K$ classes. $V$ is the vocabulary, and $C(w,x)$ is the number of times a word $w$ appears in document $x$.

The joint probability distribution is:

$$ P(x, y) = P(y)\prod P(w\mid y),\quad w\in V$$

I have to derive the update equations for the EM algorithm which maximizes the log likelihood of the incomplete data. The parameters are $P(y)$ and $P(w\mid y)$.

But I don't understand where to start. For example, how is the $Q$ equation for this problem formulated?

Comment: This sounds like a mixture estimation problem (despite atrocious notations!) EM for mixtures is fully processed [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Example:_Gaussian_mixture).